Azure Web App Deployment Stuck with Microsoft.Web/serverfarms showing BadGateway status
I'm currently working on deploying a website developed with ASP.NET 8.0 using Azure Web App Services and have encountered an issue that I'm unable to resolve. I use the Azure subscription 1 plan which is the free plan with 200$ free.
Here are the steps I've followed:

Created a Resource Group.
Created a SQL database.
Attempted to create a Web App in App Services.

During the Web App creation step, I ran into a problem. After configuring the settings with the Free F1 plan of Azure and clicking 'Create', I noticed in the results that all components were created successfully (showing an 'Ok' status), except for Microsoft.Web/serverfarms, which showed a BadGateway status. The deployment process seems to hang at this point, with no further progress even after a significant amount of time.

I've tried several troubleshooting methods and searched extensively for solutions, but haven't been able to resolve this issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, how did you manage to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.


Microsoft.Web/serverfarms, which showed a BadGateway status

To avoid the error mentioned above, ensure that you enable basic authentication when creating an Azure App Service.
I followed the same steps as you've mentioned
First, I created the SQL Database. I tried creating an Azure app service with .Net 8, and it was successfully created without any Bad Gateway errors.


And now I tried deploying the ASP.net 8 app to azure app service.

Here's the output after deployment:

